# Prove: composition of linear functions with increasing intercept

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions, linear-programming

Suppose I have three linear functions, denoted by $f_i(x) = a_i + b_i x$, $x \geq 0$, $a_i >0$, $i \in \{1,2,3\}$.

Further, I assume that $b_3 > b_2 > b_1 \geq 0$, and define
$$
g(i) = \mbox{arg}\min_i \{ f_i(x) , i = 1,2,3\},
$$
where $g(i)$ is the $i$th linear function such that $f_i(x)$ is minimized.

It seems that $g(i)$ is increasing in $x$. I want to know whether it is true for any number of linear functions instead of 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If two successive half-lines do not intersect, the second can be ignored as it never contributes to the minimum.

In a three-intersecting-half-lines configuration, if the two intersections abscissas $x_{i,i+1}$ and $x_{i+1,i+2}$ are not increasing, the line $i$ is completely above and never contributes to the minimum.

So after discarding all irrelevant lines, the pairwise intersections are indeed ordered by increasing $x$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I agree. I am interested in whether this can be proofed for any number of lines.

Comment: @YuanchenLi: you seem to miss that this is the proof for any number of lines.

Comment: You are right. This is the proof for any number of lines. Thanks.